# WordPress multi domain: page redirect to main domain whenever WordPress do the URL guessing issue

Tags: redirect, wp-redirect

I have 3 different domains for a single WordPress project (for example, [www.aaa.com](http://www.aaa.com), [www.bbb.com](http://www.bbb.com), [www.ccc.com](http://www.ccc.com)). [www.aaa.com](http://www.aaa.com) is the main domain. The problem is, whenever I access the page that WordPress did the URL guessing on other domains, it will redirect to the main domain with 301 code. Here is an example of the current situation:

```
www.aaa.com/en --> www.aaa.com/en/
www.bbb.com/en --> www.aaa.com/en/
www.ccc.com/location/ --> www.aaa.com/aboutus/location/
```

What my expectation is it will redirect according to its own domain, like:

```
www.bbb.com/en --> www.bbb.com/en/
```

I am not sure which part should I check on. I really appreciate anyone's help.

Answer (score 0):

This is intended behaviour for WordPress install and will use the value set in the `siteurl` entry in the options table.

What you want to achieve will probably have to be done with Nginx or Apache using `Rewrite`s, or `proxy_pass` (for Nginx) or `RewriteRule` and `ProxyPass` (Apache)

Comment: You could also put something in wp-config or sunrise to recognise the three valid domains (with and without www) and switch the siteurl to whichever one the request is using. Which is a bit of a hack though.